# ¿A qúe se debe? VBScript código 800a01ad

Tags: importación, vbscript, outlook

Tengo un archivo de VBS que carga archivos eml a Outlook.
Selecciona la carpeta que contiene los eml y la carpeta destino dentro de Outook. 
El mismo script fue probado en otro equipo y funciono sin problema. Solo que al ejecutarlo en otro, marca el error adjunto en la imagen.

Menciono que no están ocultas las extensiones de archivos, y que intentando otra alternativa, encontré que editando los registros de Windows de VBS para ejecución de la siguiente manera:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command to %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe "%1" %*

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command to %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe "%1" %*
```

Y abrir el archivo con: `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wscript.exe`
Pero no funcionó, ¿Que podría estar ocasionando el problema?

Línea Núm. 13 donde causa el problema:

Imágen del error al seleccionar la carpeta destino:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Línea del error: `Set objSafePost = CreateObject("Redemption.SafePostItem")`

Comment: Hola, ¿en qué sistema los estás ejecutando? ¿En uno de 32 o 64 bits?

Comment: en 64, en ambas máquinas, y en la que si funcionó, no me marco algún error como este,

Comment: @ArmandoGómez, ¿y qué versiones de Outlook hay en cada máquina? ¿32 o 64 bits?

Comment: la versión es 64 también

Answer (score 2):

Intenta registrar el componente **redemption64.dll** con el **regsvr32.exe**, el registro se hace colocando el archivo en la ruta `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` y ejecutando el comando desde `cmd` (como Administrador) como sigue:

```
regsvr32.exe C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\redemption64.dll
```

**Situación:**

De acuerdo a lo que tienes instalado (sistema operativo de 64 bits), éste error se genera cuando la versión de Microsoft Office es de 32 bits (preinstalado, otras aplicaciones de Office como Visio, Publisher, C2R - Click to Run -, etcétera), y pese a que registres la DLL, el error va a persistir por la diferencia de plataforma, en este caso la solución es desinstalar la versión de Office de 32 bits y reinstalar la versión de 64 bits.

Es importante que identifiques por completo las aplicaciones que tengas instaladas que corresponden a 32 bits para ello te recomiendo utilizar el programa [System Ninja](https://singularlabs.com/software/system-ninja/) para identificar y desinstalar aplicaciones de Office precargadas en algunos sistemas que no son visibles desde Agregar o quitar programas en Windows.

Saludos,